# can't launch .lnk files with cygwin and git-bash

Tags: cygwin

I have a problem where I can't do my `vagrant up` in cygwin, because cygwin can't understand non-POSIX style paths like `C:\`, which the vagrantfile uses.

I use `git-bash` to start vagrant, because it can understand the non-POSIX paths. To make my life even simpler, I created windows `.lnk` files to launch bash scripts in git-bash that start my ssh agent and start vagrant.

I wanted it to take a step further and use bash aliases in cygwin to create an alias for `vagrant up` that would launch my `vagrant-up.lnk`, etc, which in turn would launch a git-bash session and finally start my vagrant instance.

However, I am having a strange problem where I cannot launch `.lnk` files with cygwin nor git-bash.

```
~/Desktop
$ cygstart vagrant-up.lnk
Unable to start 'vagrant-up.lnk': The specified path was not found.
```

Thinking it was a path issue, I tried giving the full path:

```
~/Desktop
$ cygstart -o /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/user/Desktop/vagrant-up.lnk
Unable to start 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\vagrant-up.lnk': The operating system denied access to the specified file.
```

The error message seems more useful in git-bash

```
MINGW64 /c/Users/user/Desktop
$ ./vagrant-up.lnk
bash: ./vagrant-up.lnk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I googled the "bash cannot execute binary file" error, but only found results about *nix utilities compiled for the wrong architecture (e.g. AIX on x86, etc)

On Timothy Martin's suggestion, I also tried this, to no avail:

```
$ cygstart /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Desktop/vagrant-up.lnk
Unable to start 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\vagrant-up.lnk': The specified path was not found.
```

It is interesting that it uses windows-style paths in this error message, but I don't know how to turn that fact into a resolution of my problem.

In the `vagrant-up.lnk`, the `Target:` is 
`"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -l "C:\cygwin\home\user\vagrant\scripts\vagrant-up.git-bash"` and `Start in:` is in `"C:\Program Files\Git"`.

What do I need to do to launch these `.lnk` files from cygwin? They run just fine when I double-click them in Windows.

Comment: For `vagrant-up.lnk` have you tried `cygstart /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Desktop/vagrant-up.lnk`?

Comment: @TimothyMartin Just tried it; same results. I updated my question.

Comment: `cygstart vagrant-up.bash` search for a program associated to `.bash` extension and find nothing on windows extension database . Try just `vagrant-up.bash` . Additional, have you put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script ?

Comment: @matzeri I mistakenly referenced my `vagrant-up.bash` script that git-bash uses. I am trying to launch my `vagrant-up.lnk` windows shortcut through cygwin. I have updated my question; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: cygstart with a *.lnk file works for me. How have you defined the `Target` and the `Start in` of your windows link ?

Comment: @matzeri I've updated the question with that information.

Comment: Does `C:\Users\user\Desktop\vagrant-up.lnk` work from CMD ?

Comment: @matzeri Yes : /

Comment: @matzeri Maybe I can make a batch file, to launch the lnk, to launch the git-bash script ... XD